# Multiple pseudo classes on a single div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a outward border effect on a set of unlimited Divs.

[image: Image of what I mean]

So I am trying to use a mix of Pseudo classes such as :first-of-type and :nth-of-type(#) but the :nth-of-type(#) is overriding the :first-of-type.

```
.quarter > div:first-of-type { border-right:dashed #cccccc 1px; border-bottom: dashed #cccccc 1px; padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; }
.quarter > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) { border-right: none; border-bottom: dashed #cccccc 1px; }
```

So this should short all but the last and the first on the third-row which I will need to code with Jquery but I just need to know if it is possible for this to work. Oh and if anyone has a better method of doing this then by all means, help a brother out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:first-of-type` is a subset of `:nth-of-type(3n+1)` for n = 0 (because 3(0) + 1 = 1). That's why you see an override, because both rules are matching the first `div`.

As both of your selectors are equally specific and there are no other declarations in your second rule that are not present in your first rule, you can just swap the positions of your two rules for your `:first-of-type` rule to take precedence:

```
.quarter > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) { border-right: none; border-bottom: dashed #cccccc 1px; }
.quarter > div:first-of-type { border-right:dashed #cccccc 1px; border-bottom: dashed #cccccc 1px; padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Comment: I forgot to say thanks this really helped cheers BoltClock :)